# Prove that if $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, that $\{(a_n)^2\}$ converges to $a^2$ by definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Prove that if $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, that $\{(a_n)^2\}$ converges to $a^2$ by definition.

**Pf.**

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$.

This means: $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N>0, \text{s.t, if} \text{  }n>N, |a_n-a|< \epsilon$$

I want to show that:
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N>0, \text{s.t, if} \text{  }n>N, |a_n^2-a^2|< \epsilon$$

How do I use the given info? I don't know how I can manipulate it to get $a_n^2$

Comment: Had you have a look a [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019453/suppose-that-s-n-converges-to-s-prove-that-s-n2-converges-to-s2?rq=1)?

Comment: Is it $a_n^2 $ or $a_n^4$

Answer (score 1):

Write
$a_n^2-a^2
=(a_n-a)(a_n+a)
$
and assume that
$a_n$ is not too far
from $a$.

My answer here
shows that this works
for
$a_n^m$
for any $m$:

[Show that $\lim_{x \to c} x^{3}=c^{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187304/show-that-lim-x-to-c-x3-c3/2187347#2187347)

Comment: How would I do it if I had $a_n^4 - a^4$

Comment: $a_n^4-a^4 = (a_n-a)(a_n^3+...+a^3)$. Then assume that $|a_n-a| < 1$ to get an upper bound on the sum. See my linked answer for details.